# use custom fonts in tilemill?

Tags: custom-font, tilemill

It seems like this can be done... but all the suggestions I've seen online aren't working for me.  I have a customFont.ttf tile that I'm putting in this dir: 'home/greg/Documents/MapBox/project/myproject/customFont.ttf'

Then I'm using this code:

`Map { font-directory: url(customFont.ttf); }`

or

```
Map { font-directory: url(''); }
```

or

```
Map { font-directory: url(fonts/customFont.ttf); }
```

but nothing is working.  I just get en error message such as:

"Invalid value for text-face-name, the type font is expected. comicSansMs, Arial Regular (of type string) was given. (line 71)"

any tips?

Answer (score 0):

place your fonts in the folder `app/assets/fonts`, lib/assets/fonts or `vendor/assets/fonts`

If Rails 4+, you can only place your fonts in the folder `app/assets/fonts.`

In css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'customFont';
  src:url('customFont.ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: no, this didn't work.  tilemill is not quite like css